# Datepicker updates Timepicker

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datepicker, wcf-ria-services, timepicker

I have a form with a datepicker and a timepicker which both are bound to the same property from the model

here my simple Model:

```
private DateTime _end;
[Required]
public DateTime End
{
    get
    {
        return _end;
    }
    set
    {
        _end = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => End);
    }
}
```

the viewmodel has a property of the ModelObject.

My XAML looks like this

```
<sdk:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=CurrentAppointment.End, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<toolkit:TimePicker Value="{Binding Path=CurrentAppointment.End, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

is there a simple way to precent the time from changing when i pick the date (it always goes back to 00:00 because the datepicker sets the date to 2011-04-29 00:00:00) or do i have to make a property for the time in my model and put the date and the time together when i want to put it in my database?

Comment: You should probably use a custom converter, but I'm not sure if you can get the current value of the property within the Convert and ConvertBack methods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is exactly the same as

[Using silverlight datepicker and timepicker together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059095/using-silverlight-datepicker-and-timepicker-together)

**Use Converter**

Answer (score 0):

You could either decide not to use data-binding and implement your logic with events, or you could use a converter and bind its parameter to the `TimePicker`. When you change the date, you can parse the parameter and attach it to the datetime.